# Dealing with numeric range-like data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe that has values like `1,362 - 2,037`, first, how can I clean them? like getting the **mean** of these two numbers (`10 - 20` ➡ `15`), **normalizing** them or anything else? second, how can I remove the comma in `1,362` to `1362` in all rows?

#### Currently Have:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 579 | 402 - 1,120 |
| No | 1,082 | 1,361 - 2,037 |

#### Expected Output:

(mean, normalization, etc.)

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 579 | 761 |
| No | 1082 | 1699 |

shape of dataframe:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("/content/cleanedNASA.csv")
df.describe
...
> [31 rows x 9 columns]
```

thanks.

Comment: [please do not post images of data / code in the question body](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) instead post them as reproducible texts. also make sure to add an expected output for clarity of the question

Comment: *I have a CSV DataFrame* is non sense. You have either a CSV **FILE**, or a DataFrame. If you have a CSV file, please show its first lines **as text** so that we can see what delimiters are used, the format of numbers, and whether quoting applies. Also show the `read_csv` command that you use... The more early the data cleaning, the easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['y'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x']
    .str.replace('[^0-9\- ]', '') # 1. remove non-(digit/dash/space) characters
    .str.split(' - ')             # 2. split by ' - '
    .explode()                    # 3. explode the lists
).mean(level=0)                   # 4. calculate average by index

df
```

Output:

```
               x     y
0    402 - 1,120   761
1            674   674
2          3,196  3196
3          1,304  1304
4            853   853
5  1,361 - 2,037  1699
```

Comment: thanks that worked but added extra .0 at the end of the numbers. (I used a list of column names to iterate & do it to all of them)